# Occurrence of only 0, 2, 8, a, c in a sequence of hexadecimal representation of binary classification of prime numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binary

I recently began experimenting with prime numbers and made a quite interesting discovery. I stored 1 if a number is prime and 0 if the number is composite as shown in the table below.

| 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 09 | 08 | 07 | 06 | 05 | 04 | 03 | 02 | 01 | 00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

This gives the following binary number: $(0010 1000 1010 1100)_2$

Writing it in hexadecimal base I get: $28ac_{16}$

Now if I repeat this for other numbers I get the sequence:
$28ac_{16}$, $a08a_{16}$, $8a20_{16}$, $2820_{16}$, $8288_{16}$, $0208_{16}$, $28a2_{16}$, $8002_{16}$, ...

Now repeating the process for $1,000,000$ whole numbers, and counting the number of occurrences of each digit of the hexadecimal base using [this](https://gist.github.com/TheScientist466/99bd8ebeff6dce986cf0bab8b7354c19) C++ program, I am getting:

1 : 0 
2 : 35129 
3 : 0 
4 : 0 
5 : 0 
6 : 0 
7 : 0 
8 : 35275 
9 : 0 
a : 4046 
b : 0 
c : 1 
d : 0 
e : 0 
f : 0

What really interests me is why only the numbers $\{0, 2, 8, a, c\}$ occurs in the numbers of this sequence and that too $c$ with only 1 occurrence and $2$ and $8$ having relatively similar number of occurrences.

Comment: Isn't that just the consequence of the fact that all primes (except $2$) are odd? ($2$ is "responsible" for the digit `c` at the start.)

Comment: As for the number of $2$s and $8$s, these just follow the number of primes of the form $4k+1$ vs. $4k+3$ which have the same asymptotic behaviour. See [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions) for more info.

Comment: I suggest that you also count the number of occurrences of the digit 0.

Comment: What does the "x" mean here ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I did have a vague idea about c having only 1 occurrence.. and it probably is because of 2. But still it does not draw a clear picture as to why it does not occur more than once.

Comment: @StinkingBishop right, but I wonder why Chebycheff's bias does not pop up.

Comment: @peter `0x1234` is a computer programmer's notation for the base-16 numeral `1234`, which mathematicians will usually write $1234_{16}$.  I believe the notation was first used in the early 1970s in the C language.  It has become very common since then.

Comment: @Peter Why, it does: $35275>35129$.

Comment: @MJD because I am writing 0x in the front and also writing numbers like a as 000a, the progam needs to be updated to count only the significant part

Comment: @Peter true, i should probably change from ```0x1234``` to $1234_{16}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you started counting at 0 that means your hexadecimal digits contain the bits indicating the primeness of 0-3, 4-7, etc.

This means that the numbers indicating the 1st and 3rd bit of your hexademical digit will always be 0 since they represent even numbers (except for in the very first digit where 2 is a prime number).

So this eliminates the hexadecimal digits of 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, b, c, d, e, and f since those have a bit value of 1 in either the 1st or 3rd spot. This only leaves the possible values of 2, 8 and a. The exception being the first occurrence of c which is due to 2 being the only even prime number.

Now the reason why 2 and 8 are more common than a is that 2 and 8 only have 1 bit that has value 1 while a has 2 bits of value 1. Prime numbers are more "rare" than non prime numbers so we would expect hexadecimal digits with less 1 bits to be more common indeed.